# Python - Multiple Classes

Tags: python, class, if-statement, constructor

I'm getting a `Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors) TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (7 given)`. I'm only entering 6 however so i'm not sure what is going on. I'd also like some help with my inventory function. I'm trying to make a program that will allow a user to input different vehicles into an inventory along with their certain attributes. I'm awfully close to getting this done, but could use some extra eyes to hopefully see what i cannot. Any advice would be immensely appreciated.

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price):
        self.__make = make
        self.__model = model
        self.__year = year
        self.__mileage = mileage
        self.__price = price

    def iMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def iModel(self, model):
        self.__model = model

    def iYear(self, year):
        self.__year = year

    def iMileage(self, mileage):
        self.__mileage = mileage

    def iPrice(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def getMake(self):
        return self.__make

    def getModel(self):
        return self.__model

    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year

    def getMileage(self):
        return self.__mileage

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.__price



class Car(Vehicle):

    #number of doors
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
        self.__doors = doors
    def iDoors(self, doors):   
        self.__doors = doors
    def gDoors(self):
        return self.__doors


class Truck(Vehicle):

    #drive type (2 or 4 wheel drive)
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, drive):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
        self.__drive = drive
    def iDrive(self, drive):   
        self.__drive = drive
    def gDrive(self):
        return self.__drive


class SUV(Vehicle):

    #passanger capacity
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, passengers):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, passengers)
    def capacity(self, passengers):
        self.__passengers = passengers
    def gCapacity(self):
        return self.__passengers


class Inventory:

    def __init__(self, list1 = []):
        self.list1 = list1[:]
    def addVehicle(self, vehicle):
        self.list1.append(vehicle)
    def display(self):
        print("The inventory count is ", len(self.list1))
        for vehicle in self.list1:
            vehicle.display()


def main():

    inventory = Inventory()
    classType = input('Is the vehicle a car, truck, or suv?  ')
    if classType == 'car':
        make = input('Please enter the make of the car: ')
        model = input('Please enter the model of the car: ') 
        year = input('Please enter the year of the car: ')
        mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the car: ')
        price = input('Please enter the price of the car: ')
        doors = input('Please enter the amount of doors on the car: ')
        car = Car(make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
        print('Make: ', car.gMake())
        print('Model: ', car.gModel())
        print('Year: ', car.gYear())
        print('Mileage: ', car.gMileage())
        print('Price: ', car.gPrice())
        print('Number of doors: ', car.gDoors())
        print()
    elif classType == 'truck':
        make = input('Please enter the make of the truck: ')
        model = input('Please enter the model of the truck: ') 
        year = input('Please enter the year of the truck: ')
        mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the truck: ')
        price = input('Please enter the price of the truck: ')
        drive = input('Please enter 2 wheel or 4 wheel drive for the truck: ')
        truck = Truck(make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
        print('Make: ', truck.gMake())
        print('Model: ', truck.gModel())
        print('Year: ', truck.gYear())
        print('Mileage: ', truck.gMileage())
        print('Price: ', truck.gPrice())
        print('Type of drive: ', truck.gDrive())
        print()
    elif classType == 'suv':
        make = input('Please enter the make of the suv: ')
        model = input('Please enter the model of the suv: ') 
        year = input('Please enter the year of the suv: ')
        mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the suv: ')
        price = input('Please enter the price of the suv: ')
        passengers = input('Please enter the capacity of the suv: ')
        suv = SUV(make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
        print('Make: ', suv.gMake())
        print('Model: ', suv.gModel())
        print('Year: ', suv.gYear())
        print('Mileage: ', suv.gMileage())
        print('Price: ', suv.gPrice())
        print('Number of passengers: ', suv.gCapacity())
        print()
    cont = input('Would you like to add another vehicle?  y/n  ')
    if cont == 'y':
        main()
    elif cont == 'n':
        inventory.display()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing all the arguments from `Car.__init__` to `Vehicle.__init__`.  The problem is that those two functions don't have the same signature.

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    #number of doors
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price)  # no doors
        self.__doors = doors
```

Comment: Why not use `super(Vehicle, self).__init__(make, model, year, mileage, price)`?

Comment: @qwertynl -- At least for learning purposes, I think this version is more instructive.  No need to pull the magic of `super` into it.  Generally, I don't recommend blind use of `super` because of the discussion [here](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).  That doesn't mean that it has no place -- It certainly does... But more often than not, I tend to avoid it.